# tensorflow profiler shape incompatible warning

Tags: python, tensorflow

With Tensorflow profiler, I am getting a lot of warning messages of the following form "Node gradients/resnet_model/IdentityN_9_grad/cond/Pad_1 incompatible shapes: Shapes (?, 11, 11, 64) and (128, 64, 11, 11) are not compatible during training." However, the training process does not crash. Can somebody explain the nature of those messages?

Answer (score 0):

You have an undefined number of patches in one off your tf.placeholder (dim is 'None', and it is shown as '?' by the profiler). 
Even if this is ok with tensorflow, this is not supported by the profiler.
Set a hard-codded value to this dim (so for you it is 128) and those warning will not occurred again.

Please note that this profiler seams not to be maintained and it may be disable in builds of TF version 2+.

For the complementary question in the comments "*what profiler should I use for Tensorflow?*", the answer is a bit complicated as you do not state what you want to explore in your TF script with the profiler, profiler that also have an included adviser.
Assuming you want to find a bottleneck in a TF model, checking compute time and memory on a device, then the easiest tool is to create a timeline json file and then read it in a Chrome browser.

Python script would be something like :

```
# build summary for logs (to be read with tensorboard):
# ¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯
log_dir = './logs_' + datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S')
if not os.path.exists(log_dir):
    os.makedirs(log_dir)
tf.summary.scalar('loss', self.loss)
tf.summary.scalar('lr', self.lr)
tf.summary.scalar('psnr', self.psnr)
writer = tf.summary.FileWriter(log_dir, self.sess.graph)
merged = tf.summary.merge_all()
clip_all_weights = tf.get_collection("max_norm")

# enable full trace and metadata for tensorboard:
# ¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯
run_options = tf.RunOptions(trace_level=tf.RunOptions.FULL_TRACE)
run_metadata = tf.RunMetadata()

# request one TF iteration (this is a sample with a denoising CNN)
_, loss, summary = self.sess.run([self.train_op, self.loss, merged], 
            feed_dict={self.Y_: batch_clean, self.X: batch_noisy, self.lr: lr[epoch], self.psnr: self.psnr_tmp, self.is_training: True},
            options=run_options,
            run_metadata=run_metadata)
self.sess.run(clip_all_weights)

# add metadata and summary to log file:
# ¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯
writer.add_run_metadata(run_metadata, 'iter_%06d' % iter_num)
writer.add_summary(summary, iter_num)

# Create the Timeline object from metadata, and write it to a json file.
# Point Chrome browser to "chrome://tracing/" to load this json file.
# ¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯
tl = timeline.Timeline(run_metadata.step_stats)
ctf = tl.generate_chrome_trace_format(show_memory=True) #show_dataflow=True, 
with open('json.timeline/timeline_%i.json' % iter_num, 'w') as f:
    f.write(ctf)
```

Comment: "this profiler seems not to be maintained and it may be disabled" then what profiler should I use for Tensorflow?